# Import from local relative path instead of pip installed module?

Tags: python

I've installed a module using pip

```
pip install module_x -i ....
```

Now I need to add new functions to the module. So updated the source code and did the following in the `tests` directory.

Directory and files structure.

```
api
  module_x
    files ....
  tests
```

Now I want to test the code in `api/tests`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import module_x
dir(module_x)
```

However, `dir(module_x)` still doesn't show any new objects I added? It `import module_x` imported the pip installed one. (I added `print('...')` in the `__init__.py` and nothing was printed after import. How to import the module from local path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to insert the relative path in front of other path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..') # insert .. in front of other path
import module_x
```